# Have Angular 4 mat-card entirely clickable to open up contained mat-menu

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to have my entire `mat-card` clickable to open up the `mat-menu` that *may* be contained within.  I have logic to show different card content depending upon some values.  Card content can either have a `mat-menu` or not have it.

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let card of cards">
     <div *ngIf="!card.hasMenu">{{card.name}}</div>
     <div *ngIf="card.hasMenu">
         <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
            {{card.name}}
         </button>
         <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
             <button *ngFor="let amenu of card.menus" mat-menu-item>
                 <span>{{amenu.name}}</span>
             </button>
         </mat-menu>
     </div>
</mat-card>
```

If I put `[matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"` on the `mat-card` I get an error   `ERROR Error: mat-menu-trigger: must pass in an mat-menu instance.`

How do I make my `mat-card` entirely clickable to open up the menu?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether there's some problem with you adding `matMenuTriggerFor` to an element that's controller by an `*ngFor`? I had some problems previously with *ngIf that was on the `mat-menu` but not on the trigger element.

Might be worth trying to insert a testing div that just wraps the mat-card contents, but is within the `mat-card` tag itself and adding the menu trigger there to see whether that solves it.

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let card of cards">
  <div [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"> <!-- YOUR TESTING DIV -->
     <div *ngIf="!card.hasMenu">{{card.name}}</div>
     <div *ngIf="card.hasMenu">
         <button mat-icon-button>
            {{card.name}}
         </button>
         <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
             <button *ngFor="let amenu of card.menus" mat-menu-item>
                 <span>{{amenu.name}}</span>
             </button>
         </mat-menu>
     </div>
  </div>
</mat-card>
```